# Excel Formula to display multiple values using Index-Match

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a large array of data (around 50x2000) of data which basically takes the form below, although the dataset is larger as mentioned.

```
DistrictNo    LocationA    LocationB    LocationC   
-----------   ---------    ---------    ---------
0001          L1           L2            L3
0002          L1           L4
0003          L1           L5            L6
0004          L2
```

Each district can have any number of locations, and the same location can be in any number of districts, but DistrictNo will always be unique.

I need a formula, (or VBA), which will, for example, when "L1" is inputted into a cell, return a list containing 0001, 0002, 0003 and 0004, when "L2" is inputted return 0001 and 0004 and when "L5" or "L6" is entered return just 0003. Which column the location is in is irrelevant, I only need the row.

Currently I'm using multiple MATCH formulas for each column and then using a VLOOKUP on the row the MATCH formula returns but the issue with that is that on the above dataset, if L1 was entered it returns only 0001, because MATCH only works off the first value, although if L2 is entered it would return 0001 and 0004 as they are in separate columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel Match multiple criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588655/excel-match-multiple-criteria)

Comment: Please share your formula too

Comment: Any formula will be daunting. as it will need 50 columns added to: `($B$2:$B$2000 = "L1") + ($C$2:$C$2000 = "L1") + ...` as well as an array formula with using Small() to get the full list.  vba is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following UDF will do it.  :

```
Public Function DistNo(Rng As Range, crit As String, k As Long) As String
    Dim rngArr() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, h As Long

    h = 1

    rngArr = Rng

    For i = LBound(rngArr, 1) To UBound(rngArr, 1)
        For j = LBound(rngArr, 2) + 1 To UBound(rngArr, 2)
            If rngArr(i, j) = crit Then
                If h = k Then
                    DistNo = rngArr(i, 1)
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    h = h + 1
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    DistNo = CVErr(xlErrNA)


End Function
```

Place this in a module attached to the workbook.  Do not put in Worksheet code or ThisWorkbook code:

[image]

You would then call it like a normal formula:

```
=IFERROR(DistNo($A$2:$D$5,$F$2,ROW(1:1)),"")
```

And copy down as far as needed.

[image]

This will use the first column as the return value.

Comment: @baelaelael did this work for you?  If so please mark as correct.  It is something only you can do.  If not, then please let me know where it failed so I can fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I posted this just as I was leaving work yesterday and got in just this morning. What you posted works fantastically, thank you very much!

One minor improvement that could be made is that it would be useful if it could remove duplicates - there are places in my dataset where, for example, L4 might appear twice in the same row and the list shows 0002 twice. I could simply edit my dataset but I wonder if there is a easier way to do it inside the code?

Comment: @baelaelael See edit, I added an Exit For to deal with duplicates.  Please mark as correct by clicking the grey-green check mark by the upper left corner of the answer.  It is something only you can do.