# Multiple Cells Criteria Vlookup with out helper Column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I'm trying to create a Vlookup or a function that will act as a Vlookup that can use data from three columns without using a helper column (my spreadsheet is large and I would like to have as few columns as possible).

[image]

Here is a snap of my spreadsheet.  I need a formula that can look up 'Industry Group,' 'Industry Subgroup,' 'Geo Focus,' and pull the data in the 'Proxy' column.  Each Combination of the first three columns has a unique value in the 'Proxy' column, but none of the values in the first three columns are unique by themselves.

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588655/excel-match-multiple-criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Index() and Match() functions to make this happen.  Take a look at this example:

Be sure to use 'Ctrl+Shift+Enter' since this is an array formula:

```
=index(B26:E31,match(B3&C3&D3,B26:B31&C26:C31&D26:D31, 0), 4)
```

If you want a video example, checkout this link: http://www.cruter.com/u/o3m... link expires in 10 days.

[image: Create a lookup formula without using a helper column... Use Index and Match functions to achieve this! - Checkout cruter.com]